# Creating an index on a column to run queries for NULL values

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing, database-performance

We are using SQL Server 2008. We have table with a couple million rows. We have one column that is NULLABLE but very few rows will have this column set as NULL. Maybe 100-200 rows out of millions.

We have a query to select these rows and we have an index on that column. For example

```
SELECT
    tbl1.Col1,
    tbl1.Col2,
    tbl1.Col3,
    tbl1.Col4,
    tbl1.Col5,
    tbl1.Col6
    tbl2.Col1,
FROM
    tbl1
    INNER JOIN tbl2 ON (tbl1.FK = tbl2.PK)
WHERE
    tbl1.NullableColumn IS NULL
```

Unfortunately we need a few of tbl1 columns (I am not sure how many columns is too many for use as included columns but we have 18 columns from tbl1 that we absolutely need). When we run this query the optimizer keeps suggesting an index on tbl.NullableColumn but we already have one. It is just not being used, even with a an index hint it is still not being used.

The execution plan says that it is doing an index seek on IX_tbl1_NullableColumn and then a keylookup on the clustered index (the keylookup takes 99% of the time).

1. I have come across some people that say you should never use a NULLABLE column as index. Is this true? Does it apply in this case?
2. Is there a smarter way of finding the handful of NULL values in the table?

Comment: I'm confused. You claim the index is not used (not even with a hint?!) and in next paragraph you are saying there is "index seek on IX_tbl1_NullableColumn" in query plan. The plan clearly says the problem is with retrieving those 18 columns you absolutely need + FK, not the index itself. So if performance of this particular query is your priority, then include those columns. It would help if we could see the query plan and IO stats otherwise we cannot be sure where that 99% come from.

Comment: @TomT I am confused too and it is exactly as I stated. The execution plan includes an index seek on the index that the optimizer claims is missing. So I am not sure why it thinks it is missing because it is using. We have 3 other servers where this is working 100% and the optimizer is not suggesting the index. But they are on SP3 and this one in question is on SP2. We will update and if it is still an issue then I will post back.

Comment: @TomT Installed the service pack, now on SP3 and the problem has gone away. No more crazy suggestions for missing indexes. We didn't even rebuild the index or update the stats. I can't find anything in their release notes though.

Comment: thanks for sharing your findings. I will try to remeber this problem with SP2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying SP3 to SQL Server fixed this issue. It is weird and I cannot explain it. I also cannot see anything about it in the release notes. I don't know if the server just needed a reboot or if it really was SP3 that solved the issue. I think it might be SP3 because all our other servers were running SP3 and they were not showing the same problem.